# JQ Query - Restructuring a nested JSON

Tags: python, json, jq

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "order": [
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "name": "Item 1",
              "id": [],
              "type": [
                {
                  "name": "Color",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "blue"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "model",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "Stereo"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "name": "Item 2",
              "id": [],
              "type": [
                {
                  "name": "Color",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "Yellow"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "model",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "NewModel"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": "715874"
    },
    {
      "order": [
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "name": "Item 6",
              "id": [],
              "type": [
                {
                  "name": "Range",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "10"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "Type",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "AllRegion"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "name": "Item 4",
              "id": [],
              "type": [
                {
                  "name": "Color",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "Yellow"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "model",
                  "value": [
                    {
                      "value": "OldModel"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": "715875"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to convert to this format

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "type": {
            "Color": "blue",
            "model": "Stereo"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "NewModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715874"
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 6",
          "type": {
            "Color": "blue",
            "Type": "AllRegion"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 4",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "OldModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715875"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using queries like this, not able to achieve the format i am looking for..

.orders[] |  { orders : [ .order[] |{ .order[].items : .], id  : .id } ]}

{ orders : [ .orders[] |{ order : [.items[].name[] ], id  : .id } ]}

Please help. thanks in Advance.  I am parsing this in Python, if any other Lib can parse this similar to JQ thats also helpfull.

Comment: Where did this structure come from? It looks entirely made-up. For instance `value` is inside of a `dict` which is the sole item in a `list` named `value`. I'm asking because, if you made this based on some other information, parsing this is a waste of time. The original data should be gathered better, and showing you how to parse the original data will be more helpful than trying to fix this.

Comment: @OysterShucker yes, i made this output json myself. I want to simply the json so that it can be parsed easily. Can you share how to represent it better? So that it's a simple JSON

Comment: Where did the data come from? I can't show you how to do it better if I have no clue where you got it. Fix your answer to explain where this data came from.

Comment: Also, include the code you used to turn the data into this structure. That's what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Aksanth In your desired output, why does `Item 6` have `"Color": "blue"`?

Comment: If you want to stick to jq syntax, there is a module on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/jq/

Answer (score 0):

Using jq, just define for each field what it should iterate over and collect:

```bash
{
  order: .orders | map({
    items: .order | map(
      .items[] | {name, type} | .type |= (map(
        .value |= .[].value
      ) | from_entries)
    ),
    id
  })
}
```

```json
{
  "order": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "type": {
            "Color": "blue",
            "model": "Stereo"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "NewModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715874"
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 6",
          "type": {
            "Range": "10",
            "Type": "AllRegion"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 4",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "OldModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715875"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zs3XSIYn_DA)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the json module. Suppose your original json is stored as `original_data`.

Then you can iterate over it to construct your desired format:

- For each order, it create a new entry
- For each item in the order, extract the name of the item and organize the "type" information into a dictionary where the "name" becomes a key, and the "value" becomes the corresponding value.
- This transformed data is stored in a new data structure
- store the new structure as json with `.dumps`

So code would be like this:

```py
    import json
    # Initialize the result structure
    result_data = {"order": []}
    
    # Iterate through "orders"
    for order_info in original_data["orders"]:
        order = {"items": [], "id": order_info["id"]}
    
        # Iterate through the "order" items
        for item in order_info["order"]:
            item_data = {
                "name": item["items"][0]["name"],
                "type": {}
            }
    
            # Iterate through "type" 
            for type_entry in item["items"][0]["type"]:
                item_data["type"][type_entry["name"]] = type_entry["value"][0]["value"]
    
            order["items"].append(item_data)
    
        result_data["order"].append(order)
    
    # Convert the result to JSON format
    result_json = json.dumps(result_data, indent=2)
    
    # Print the resulting JSON
    print(result_json)
```

Which yields the following JSON (as desired):

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "type": {
            "Color": "blue",
            "model": "Stereo"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "NewModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715874"
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 6",
          "type": {
            "Range": "10",
            "Type": "AllRegion"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 4",
          "type": {
            "Color": "Yellow",
            "model": "OldModel"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "715875"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please validate your response with output obtained using provided input.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A0pMZGQtlr6)) without using nested mutations (`|=`):

```
def transform:
    { name, type : [ .type[] | { (.name) : .value[].value } ] | add };

{ order : [ .orders[] | { items: [ .order[].items[] | transform ], id } ] }
```

We keep the transformation of the `items` in a separate function for readability.